# Comparing in Bitwise operations

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Code always print 0. I thought it was a comparison problem but the same output came to me again.

**Function Description:**
Complete the calculate_the_maximum function in the editor below.

**calculate_the_maximum has the following parameters:**

int n: the highest number to consider
int k: the result of a comparison must be lower than this number to be considered
Prints

Print the maximum values for the and, or and xor comparisons, each on a separate line.

**My C code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Complete the following function.


void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) {
  //Write your code here.
  int AND=0,OR=0,XOR=0;
  for(int x=1; x<=n ; x++)
    {
        for(int y = x; y<=n; y++)
        {
            if((x&y)>AND) AND = x&y;
            if((x|y)>OR) OR = x|y;
            if((x^y)>XOR) XOR = x^y;
        }
    }
    if(XOR>k || XOR<2 || XOR>n){XOR = 0;}
    if(OR>k || OR<2 || OR>n) OR = 0;
    if(AND>k || AND<2 || AND>n) AND = 0;
    
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d",AND,OR,XOR);
    
}

int main() {
    int n, k;
  
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    calculate_the_maximum(n, k);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to put the conditions with `k` inside the inner loop.

Comment: I tried to put it inside 2nd for loop but the output was :
0 0 1
Expected output:
2 3 3

n = 5 , k=4

Comment: The if() statements just before printf() in  calculate_the_maximum() seem to have potential to set variables XOR, AND, OR to zero for *an awful lot of cases.*   Are you sure they are correct?  For me, these 3 lines are prime suspects for why zero is always printed.          :::::: Suggestion:::::::  comment out those 3 lines and see if output is closer to expectations.  Then uncomment them one at a time to help you find the pain point.

Comment: Yes, those if() statements are absolutely setting XOR, OR and AND variables to zero for test case  n = 5 , k=4.  
[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/6qoG6zsdE) is the runnable code for anyone to examine and experiment with.  Enable each of the 3 if() statements one at a time and watch each variable go to zero, one by one.     --- This doesn't prove that's the only pain point, of course. ---